# Perform If statements for a specific file name in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a Rewrite rule but i want the rewrite rule to only run when the page is not index.php, I have tried using If statement, all but no avail. My code, what I have tried.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^index$ ./index.php // i did a URL rewrite for removing the .php 

<If "%{HTTP_HOST } == 'index'">
// do nothing here else 
</If>
<Else> //run the code in the else statement.
RewriteRule ^ profile.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^ zprofile.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^zprofile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) zprofile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
</Else>
```

Comment: Change `index` to the actual URL.

Comment: @Lag response server error.

Comment: @Chris85 Thanks, but please I really don't understand, please could you give an example below as an accepted answer.

Comment: @Shasha Please give the example below a try.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ profile.php [NC,L]` and `RewriteRule ^ zprofile.php [NC,L]` don't make any sense as they both rewrite **everything** to `profile.php` since 2nd rule will never execute. What are they supposed to be doing?

Comment: Also understand difference between `HTTP_HOST` and `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: @anubhava I reworked my code and took another approach, since i have like 10 files on my main directory I then want to check if the file does not exist on the server it should perform a rewrite rule  like this 
  RewriteRule ^ profile.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: ok then please update the question with your latest attempt so that we can suggest correct approach.

Comment: @chris85: No because `%{HTTP_HOST}` can never be `index`. It holds value as `ww.example.com`

Comment: @anubhava Ah, yea that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after a lack lustre night, with this simple code below, but I did it with another approach, instead of use if statement, i simply rewrote the pages i knew where on my directory first so any page that does not exist on my directory should be redirected to a particular page with the url being the same.

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^zindex$ zindex.php //file in the directory

RewriteRule ^index$ index.php //file in the directory

RewriteRule ^zprofile$ zprofile.php //file in the directory

RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [NC] //file in the directory


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f //if file does not exist in directory redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d //if file does not exist in directory redirect
RewriteRule ^.*$ profile.php [L] //to profile.php page with the URL still being the same.
```