# .htaccess rewrite rule to not include index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess rule that GETs the first directory part of the url and uses that to look up the product from the database as follows www.website.com/product-1. I use the following rule, and it works fine:

`RewriteRule    ^([-_a-z0-9]+)?$   /product.php?product_url=$1    [NC,L]`

The problem is, when I visit the home page www.website.com/ it tries to look for a blank product. If I want to visit the home page, I have to use www.website.com/index.php.

How can I keep the url structure I have above, but make www.website.com/ show the home page index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should skip index.php

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([-_a-z0-9]+)?$   /product.php?product_url=$1    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Main issue is with your regex that also matches an empty string.

You should be using this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([-_a-z0-9]+)/?$ product.php?product_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This regex makes trailing slash optional in request URI but doesn't match empty string (landing page)

Additionally consider using these 2 conditions to skip all files and directories from this rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-_a-z0-9]+)/?$ product.php?product_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I added those two `REQUEST_FILENAME` rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : ALSO check and modify this question I once asked to see if you can tweak it up [Perform If statements for a specific file name in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440106/perform-if-statements-for-a-specific-file-name-in-htaccess)

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] //This would make it skip index.php and look at product.php
RewriteRule ^([-_a-z0-9]+)?$   /product.php?product_url=$1    [NC,L]
```